# How to find limit of integral where function under integral depends on limit variable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

My task is formulated as follows: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{cos(t^{3})}{t+x} dt$$

Solution of that limit here: [Limit under integral problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544483/limit-under-integral-problem)

But I'm searching general tips how to find such limits: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x,t) dt$$

Here we can't differentiate our integral or simply apply l'Hopital's rule. And that task seems without having any general techniques to get solution.

Comment: You *can* apply L'Hopitl's, just use the complete version of Leibniz formula for differentiating an integral

Comment: For your concrete problem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3544483/42969

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to apply L'Hopital's Rule. By MVT for integrals, there is $c$ between $0$ and $x$ such that
$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\cos(t^{3})}{t+x} dt=\cos(c^3)\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{t+x} dt=\cos(c^3)\ln2 $$
and hence
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\cos(t^{3})}{t+x} dt=\lim_{x\to0}\cos(c^3)\ln2=\ln2. $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach to the general case using Leibniz rule
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t,x)dt=$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}xf(t,x)dt=$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}x f(t,x)dt}{x}$$
Now, Leibniz rule for differentiating an integral tells us that if $$I(\alpha)=\int_{a(\alpha)}^{b(\alpha)}f(t,\alpha)dt$$
then
$$\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}\alpha}=\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}dt+f(b,\alpha)\frac{\text{d}b}{\text{d}\alpha}-f(a,\alpha)\frac{\text{d}a}{\text{d}\alpha}$$
In our case $$I(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} xf(t,x) dt$$
So we **can** perform L'Hopital's trick  to evaluate the limit.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: *Just for the fun :* At the price of a very simple approximation , the original integral is $$\log (2)+\frac{37-60 \log (2)}{12 \pi ^2}x^6+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, for sure. If you have time to waste, plot the two functions  for $-1\leq x \leq 1$. Cheers :-)

Comment: I'll do, thanks. Btw, how did you get the neat approximation? Is there some trick? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Just using my favored $1,400^+$ years old approximation of the cosine function. $$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad (-\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2)$$

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici
 I find $120$ instead of your $12\pi^2$ in the approximation